# Rails / Error Bundler::HTTPError during request to dependency API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dependencies, bundler, rails-engines

I have a cms engine that I created not long back, I have used it many times with no problems. But as of today I keep getting this error when trying to update the engine/gem or if I push it to Heroku.

This is the error I get:

```
Error Bundler::HTTPError during request to dependency API
```

I know that the Rubygems "Dependency API" has been down over the last couple of days. But it should be up again. How can I troubleshoot this error further and determin whether this is a problem on my side or with Rubygems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This answer may not be valid anymore, as the original question is about an older issue with the Rubygems Dependency API, which has been fixed.**

Check out this mailing-list thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubygems-org/zP-lZ-lCbqM

According to it, a *very* temporary-only solution would be to replace

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

with

```
source "http://bundler-api.herokuapp.com"
```

I also quote another [mailing-list reply](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubygems-org/L4dkcw8Axfk/5jlTt-2ssXIJ):

> Just for the record, the reason it worked for you is that Bundler
> works just fine without the dependency API. It's a little slower,
> granted, but any Gemfile source line that worked before is going to
> keep working now.